# why need three pairs of keys rather than three keys in TLS handshake?

Tags: ssl, encryption, tls1.2

At the end of the TLS handshake, the master key extends into six values for symmetric encryption.

- server write key
- client write key
- server write IV
- client write IV
- server write MAC key
- client write MAC key

Take the write key as an example, the server will use the server write key to encrypt the data, and when the client receive the data, it will use the server write key to decrypt. And when client send data to the server, they will use the client write key.
My question is what are the benefits of using a pair of write key?
if they use the same value for both reading and writing, will it cause some problems?

Comment: The benefits of separate keys in each direction is that it makes it twice as hard to crack the conversation. An IV is not a key.

Comment: This is not a programming issue and belongs on crypto.SX or possibly security.SX. First, your list is only correct for SSL3 through TLS1.2; TLS1.3 changes the key (and IV) schedule radically. kx-created IVs are not used for CBC in 1.1 and 1.2, and only for part of the IV for (some) AEAD ciphers in 1.2. (And of course they are never used for the only stream cipher through 1.2, RC4, which shouldn't be used at all.) And separate MAC keys are not used for AEAD in 1.2. ...

Comment: ... If you do use the same key and IV for both directions with a stream or counter-based (GCM, CCM) cipher it creates the 'two-time pad' frequently condemned and mocked in crypto.SX which often allows an adversary to decrypt the data that was intended and promised to be private. If you use them with CBC (which would only happen in 1.0 and only apply to the first data record, and maybe not that if anti-BEAST fragmentation is implemented) it breaks semantic security (allows recognizing duplicates) but no more.

Comment: E.g. see https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/50799/the-number-of-keys-generated-in-tls-1-2